# How do I wipe the data in a kernel module variable?

Tags: kernel-module

I have a kernel module that checks the IP address of a requests and adds it to a "blacklist" variable if the request contains bad data (spam keywords).

The way I declare the blacklist is as follows:

```
#define blacklist (uint32_t[3]) { \
  2071690107, \
  168430090, \
  4294967295 \
}
```

I did some initial testing reaching this step (filtering IPv4, printk logs) and must have already blocked an ip address of one of the requests I need to test.

I say this because when I do a make clean, make, and reinsert my module, I automatically see the IP address blocked.

What should happen is the data prints first showing a spam word, then it blocks the IP address, then it will print it is already blocked on any subsequent requests (which I know will follow shortly after).

```
Mar 16 18:43:33 deadsupra-VirtualBox kernel: [36594.961054] Module insertion completed successfully!
Mar 16 18:43:46 deadsupra-VirtualBox kernel: [36607.186539] ip checking: 127.0.0.1
Mar 16 18:43:46 deadsupra-VirtualBox kernel: [36607.186541] ip is already blacklisted 127.0.0.1
Mar 16 18:43:46 deadsupra-VirtualBox kernel: [36607.186546] ip checking: 127.0.0.1
Mar 16 18:43:46 deadsupra-VirtualBox kernel: [36607.186547] ip is already blacklisted 127.0.0.1
Mar 16 18:43:51 deadsupra-VirtualBox kernel: [36612.190103] ip checking: 127.0.0.1
Mar 16 18:43:51 deadsupra-VirtualBox kernel: [36612.190108] ip is already blacklisted 127.0.0.1
Mar 16 18:43:51 deadsupra-VirtualBox kernel: [36612.190119] ip checking: 127.0.0.1
Mar 16 18:43:51 deadsupra-VirtualBox kernel: [36612.190121] ip is already blacklisted 127.0.0.1
```

My make file is as follows:

```
obj-m += wander.o 

KERNELDIR ?= /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build

all:
    make -C $(KERNELDIR) -Wno-declaration-after-statement M=$(PWD) modules 

clean:
    make -C $(KERNELDIR) M=$(PWD) clean

insert:
    -sudo rmmod wander
    sudo dmesg -C
    sudo insmod wander.ko
    dmesg

test:
    curl "http://www1.udel.edu/registrar/graduation-diplomas/diplomas.html" | grep -i -o -P '.{0,10}university.diploma.{0,20}'

log:
    cat /var/log/kern.log
```

Am I not cleaning my project space properly? I want to refresh my test scenario every time and forget about any ip addresses previously blocked when I rebuild my source code.

I'm thinking that when I clean the module, it removes it but must be keeping the data for some reason.

Comment: Note, that upon removing the module, only the memory occupied by its code and data is freed; other resources (e.g. the memory allocated in the module's code with `kmalloc`) is not freed automatically. When you insert the module again, its code and data are loaded into the memory, allocated for the module; nothing else is changed automatically. You ask us why your new module accesses your old data, but only the **module's code may answer on this question**. Probably, you module accesses to old data somehow. Again, only the module's code may help with finding the reason of this.